# Avoid UAC prompt in Qt 5.1 lupdate

Tags: qt, windows-7, uac

I am using Qt 5.1.0 with the bundled mingw 4.8 (32 bit) on Win7 64.

I want to run `lupdate.exe` to create and update the translation files. However, every run of lupdate demands administrator access rights and I get the windows UAC prompt I need to accept. This is annoying.
This issue only arises at lupdate. lrelease as well as all other Qt tools run as expected.

Not sure whether this is relevant: lupdate.exe is installed in the default path, C:\Qt\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin\lupdate.exe.

I do not see any reason why lupdate needs admin rights and this was also not the case in former versions. So, why does my installation prompt for them? How can I avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exe name like update.exe blocked by UAC in scheduled task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222217/exe-name-like-update-exe-blocked-by-uac-in-scheduled-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Windows checks the file name and **assumes** that anything containing "update", "install", or "uninstall" in its file name is an installer, and requires administrative privileges to run, regardless of whether it has manifest or not. This is done so old legacy installers created before UAC existed would continue to work.

Rename "lupdate.exe" to something that doesn't contain "update", and the UAC prompts will stop.

Comment: It *can* be disabled by the manifest, but mingw doesn't do it, afaik.